# nodejs - trying to get the variable outside from an async/await function but getting a promise pending error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

This is what I have:

```
async function myFetch() {
    let loggerinfo = {
        url: await "Hellothere",
        token: await "212312"
    };

    return await loggerinfo;
  
  }
  
const myfish = myFetch().then((loggerinfo) => {
      return loggerinfo
  })

console.log(myfish);
```

i am getting an "Promise {  }" when I output myfish variable

I require the async and await attributes but at the same time, i need to be able to use the loggerinfo variable which "myfish" to be used outside of async and myFetch().then boxes.

my result would be like for example:

```
async function myFetch() {
    let loggerinfo = {
        url: await "Hellothere",
        token: await "212312"
    };

    return await loggerinfo;

  }

const myfish = myFetch().then((loggerinfo) => {
      return loggerinfo
  })
```

### use myfish inside exports.handler

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
     console.log(myfish);
};
```

Comment: hi if you want to use method my fetch than you need to add export module first and than try it out

Comment: yea, i had to place it inside the exports.handler and that worked but this is why I am asking in here if there is a way to keep that outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function myFetch() {
    let loggerinfo = {
       url: await "Hellothere",
       token: await "212312"
    };
    return loggerinfo;
}
const myfish = async () => {return await myFetch();}
```

Use the above code to get your expected result.

**use myfish inside exports.handler**

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) {
 console.log(await myfish);
}
```

You can use async/await in your lambda function also as mentioned above

Comment: I get a const myfish = await myFetch();   ^^^^^  SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function error

Comment: Hi @sdas2 , I have corrected the code above. Use async await through out your code which makes your code easy to use and read. Try the above code.

Comment: thanks. I have yet to test it. i'll let you know

Comment: Sure @sdas2 test it

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function myFetch() {
  let loggerinfo = {
    url: "Hellothere",
    token: "212312"
  };

  return await loggerinfo;

}

  (async () => {
    console.log(await myFetch())
  })()
```